# What is the correct definition of a heap

Tags: data-structures, heap

I was reading about heaps in Java programming. In my textbook, I found this definition of a heap: a heap is a complete binary tree with the following properties: 1) the value in the root is the **smallest** item in the tree;
2) every subtree is a heap

But when I was watching videos about heaps, I found a totally different definition of heaps which says: In a heap the parent keys are **bigger** then the children.

Now I am confused because the two definitions do not fit with each other.
Which definition is the correct one?

Thanks!

Comment: Wiki says quite clear bout it: A heap can be classified further as either a "max heap" or a "min heap". In a max heap, the keys of parent nodes are always greater than or equal to those of the children and the highest key is in the root node. In a min heap, the keys of parent nodes are less than or equal to those of the children and the lowest key is in the root node.

Comment: thank you .. I have one more question : does the Time Complexity O(n log(n)) of a heap is also written like O(log(n)) ..  http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: @AllaAls: On heap, which operation's complexity are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both the definition are correct.**

There are **two** types of `Heap`.

**Min Heap:** In which parent node is always `smaller` than its children.

**Max Heap:** In which, parent node is always `larger` than its children.

This `smaller/larger` value of the parent than it's children is called **Heap Property**. This `Heap Property` has be satisfied by each node of the tree.

The complexity of `constructing the Heap` from a given array is `O(n)`. This operation is called **`Heapify`**.

Given a Heap, adding/removing a node/element from the Heap. The complexity of the operation is `O(log(n))`.

The complexity of the Sorting any array using the Heap data structure (**Heap Sort**) is `O(n.log(n))`. Basically you extract the top (root) element from the `Min Heap`. This operation is repeated `n` times, So complexity is `O(n.log(n))`

Comment: thank you .. I have one more question : does the Time Complexity O(n log(n)) of a heap is also written like O(log(n)) ..  http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: @AllaAls `O(log(n)) [Heapify Operation]` and `O(n log(n)) [Heap Sort Algorithm]` are two completely different things. Can you ask more specifically.

Comment: if you look at below question in link, you will find in the first answer that the programmer says to the asker that  the Time Complexity of a heap is  written like O(log(n)) ... Please see the question and answer .. thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645907/why-use-heap-instead-of-binary-tree-when-implementing-priority-queue?rq=1

Comment: He talking about the Heapify Operation. Which removing/adding an element to the heap. The complexity for that is `O(log(n))`. But if you are sorting the elements using the Heap then complexity is `O(n log(n))`. So both the complexities are for two different operations.

Comment: God bless you brother :)

Comment: I will add the information in the answer so that it will be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))

> In computer science, a heap is a specialized tree-based data structure
>   that satisfies the heap property: If A is a parent node of B then the
>   key of node A is ordered with respect to the key of node B with the
>   same ordering applying across the heap. A heap can be classified
>   further as either a "max heap" or a "min heap". In a max heap, the
>   keys of parent nodes are always greater than or equal to those of the
>   children and the highest key is in the root node. In a min heap, the
>   keys of parent nodes are less than or equal to those of the children
>   and the lowest key is in the root node. Heaps are crucial in several
>   efficient graph algorithms such as Dijkstra's algorithm, and in the
>   sorting algorithm heapsort. A common implementation of a heap is the
>   binary heap, in which the tree is a complete binary tree (see figure).

There are 2 types of heaps:

**Min Heap**: Parent node is always smaller than the childeren.

**Max Heap**: Parent node is always larger than the childeren.